# Furigana rendering problem

Tags: support, furigana

I tried to edit [a question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15791/how-to-parse-%E5%8F%8B%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB%E3%80%9C%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F) where some kanji were followed by kana. I wanted to transform kana into furigana.

Original: ある夏の午後京浜電車けいひんでんしゃの中で

Furigana doesn't want to render correctly and starts too early (over 午後):

ある夏の午後京浜電車{けいひんでんしゃ}の中で

I tried combinations below (I used parentheses to show combinations I tried without rendering) - all give incorrect result:

ある夏の午後京浜(けいひん)電車(でんしゃ)の中で gives ある夏の午後京浜{けいひん}電車{でんしゃ}の中で

ある夏の午後京(けい)浜(ひん)電(でん)車(しゃ)の中で gives ある夏の午後京{けい}浜{ひん}電{でん}車{しゃ}の中で

Is there a way to render this furigana correctly?

ある夏の午後京浜電車(けいひんでんしゃ)の中で gives ある夏の午後京浜電車{けいひんでんしゃ}の中で

Comment: Ooops I didn't notice this post 編集しちゃった・・・スマソ！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put square brackets around the kanji and curly brackets around the kana:

> ある夏の午後[京浜電車]​{けいひんでんしゃ}の中で

It should look like this:

> ある夏の午後[京浜電車]{けいひんでんしゃ}の中で

In the first quote above, I used a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) to prevent the furigana markup from rendering for demonstration purposes, so if you copy and paste that block it won't work.  But if you type it like that, it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much!